# How to select row based on max column and latest in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my table in PostgreSQL:

| id | name | description | account_id | total_sales | create_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Playstation 4 | Console Game | 1 | 21 | 2021-03-26 |
| 2 | Playstation 2 | Console Game | 1 | 21 | 2021-03-27 |
| 3 | Playstation 3 | Console Game | 1 | 20 | 2021-03-27 |

I would like to select row based on max(total_sales). If there are two rows with same total_sales, it will select the latest.

So, the result should be like this:

| id | name | description | account_id | total_sales | create_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Playstation 2 | Console Game | 1 | 21 | 2021-03-27 |

If there is only one row with max(total_sales) and there is no same value, it will return this row as the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from your_table
order by toal_sales desc, created_at desc
limit 1
```